# How to grant select on a view ... based on IP adress?

Tags: postgresql, view, permissions, access-control

I wonder if it's possible to allow a client A to "see" some data in a view while allowing any other clients, namely B and C, to see ALL data from the same view.

The distinction between A, B and C would rely on their IP address.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to write a *function* that checks the client's IP address and then runs different SELECT statements based on that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Client A makes direct request to the database. How can I intercept those requests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [session information function `inet_client_addr()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE), with limited reach. It reports the IP the server is receiving the current connection from. This is only useful with direct connections to the database, though.

As proof of concept:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN inet_client_addr() << '192.168.1.32/30'::inet
         THEN 'foo'
         ELSE 'bar'
       END AS odd_column
```

[`<<`.. "is contained within" operator.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-net.html)

As [@Craig mentioned in a comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61394/how-to-grant-select-on-a-view-based-on-ip-adress/61405?noredirect=1#comment110505_61405), consider the `security_barrier` option for a view like that:

```
CREATE VIEW my_odd_view WITH (security_barrier) AS ...
```

Details in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-privileges.html).

The whole idea is rather dubious, though. The proper way would be to use distinct roles and distinct views with grants only for privileged roles.

Comment: You'd want to use a `security_barrier` view too, to prevent leakage via user-defined-function predicates.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Excellent point. I added a bit to the answer.